# Program calls printf() then loops forever. Why don't I see the printf output?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, while-loop, printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
  
struct my_Struct{
    int a;
    int b;
};
void *myThreadFun(void *received_struct)
{
    struct my_Struct *struct_ptr = (struct my_Struct*) received_struct;
    printf("%.1lf",pow(struct_ptr->a,struct_ptr->b));
    return NULL;
}
   
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct my_Struct s;
    s.a = atoi(argv[1]);
    s.b = atoi(argv[2]);
    
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, &s);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    while(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Why does this code do nothing? It is supposed to print statement in the spawned thread and then go into infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I assume your assumption is wrong and you just don't see the output. Printing to `stdout` is typically line buffered. This means you either need to put a `\n` at the end of your output or use `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Had you ended the printf with a newline your output buffer would be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, both of these solve the issue.

Comment: I changed the title of your question so that other people having a similar problem may be more likely to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gdb we can see the thread forked successfully

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff7a2d640 (LWP 8261)]
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7a2d640 (LWP 8261)]

Thread 2 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 1, myThreadFun (received_struct=0x7fffffffd960) at tmp.cpp:15
```

If you delete the `while(1)` you can find the output. The delay in output may related to the stdio's buffer, `while(1)` prevented the buffer from flushing.

You can try another approach: add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`, this works the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `stdout` buffers whole lines, so it means it won't print your values until you do one of three things:

- end your string with `\n`: `printf("%.1lf\n", ...)`
- flush the stdio buffer: `fflush(stdout)`
- terminate the program (it will flush all buffers automatically)